# httpURLConnection with name values pairs, SSL, upload, and response handling

Tags: apache, ssl, httpurlconnection

I'm searching for a way to convert from Apache HTTP to HTTPurlConnection while using SSL, response handling and file uploads, all at the same time.  This is fairly easy in an Apache httpPost (I'm importing the httpmime.jar now) but I'm not finding a clean way to do it with the new HTTPURLConnection.  Can anyone show some examples on doing this?

Here is a sample of current Apache code that I was to convert to httpURLConnection (in this example a file was not uploaded but in some cases it is):

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User Name", "loginName"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "loginPassword"));

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FromUser", sEmail));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CommentsTo", sEmail));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MyVersion", MainActivity.version));

    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),  
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("loginCredentials", "loginPasswordCredentials");
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://hostingservername/hostingserverdirectory/PHPhandlerfile.php");
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpEntity entity = httpPost.getEntity();


    sReceiveResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
    if( entity != null ) entity.consumeContent();  // release connection

    // handle sReceiveResponse return
```

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` is not new, it is 20 years old.

Comment: What I meant was that it is now the recommended method, from what I've read on this site.  I'm looking to update my HTTPpost code to current standards.  I've had some issues with Proguard properly recognizing the Apache code too, and I thought this might help with Proguard as well.